# Wordpress Sidebar on Widget Section is not displaying upon Custom Plugin Activation

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

```
    Hello Team,

    I am using the latest version of WordPress(4.7.2). My custom plugin works smoothly up to 4.5.2. when I tried to install the plugin, upon activation, on the widget area section, sidebar section is not displayed.
```

The plugin is working smoothly on previous Wordpress versions. But now it's not showing. Please help me to find a solution.

I am stuck with this for past few days. It will be helpful if you guys help me to find the best solution. [see the admin area widget display][1]

```
    Please see the following code:

    <?php
    /**
     * Add actions to widgets_init to load the widget.
     */
    add_action("widgets_init", "daily_quotes_load_widgets");
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "daily_quotes_enqueue_scripts");


    /*
    * fucntion to display contents in the webpage
    * @param null
    * @return display contents in a webpage
    */


    if (!function_exists('writeLog')) {

        /**
         * Function to add the plugin log to wordpress log file, added by BDT
         * @param object $log
         */
        function writeLog($log, $line = "",$file = "")  {

            if (WP_DEBUG === true) {

                $pluginLog = $log ." on line [" . $line . "] of [" . $file . "]\n";

                if ( is_array( $pluginLog ) || is_object( $pluginLog ) ) {
                    print_r( $pluginLog, true );
                } else {
                    error_log( $pluginLog );
                }

            }
        }

    }


    /**
     * function to register the widget "daily_quotes"
     * @author Test
     */
    function daily_quotes_load_widgets() {
        register_widget("Daily_Quotes");
    }

    /**
     * function to enqueue the styles and scripts used in the widget "daily_quotes"
     * @author Test
     */
    function daily_quotes_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style("styles", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "styles.css");
        wp_enqueue_script("scripts", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "scripts.js", array("jquery"), "1.0.0", true);
    }

    /**
     * Daily_Quotes: Class which contains the functions for the display of the Daily Quote widget
     *
     * @author  Test
     */
    class Daily_Quotes extends WP_Widget {

        protected $plugin_slug;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        function Daily_Quotes() {
            include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'class-quotery-quote.php' );
            $this->plugin_slug = Quotery_Quote::get_instance()->get_plugin_slug();
            $idBase = "daily_quotes_id";
            $name = "Daily Quotes";
            $description = "A widget that displays the daily inspirational quotes.";

            /* Widget settings. */
            $widgetOptions = array(
                "classname" => "daily_quotes", // CSS classname of the widget container
                "description" => $description // widget description which appears in admin area (Available widgets)
            );

            /* Widget control settings. */
            $controlOptions = array(
                "width" => 250, // width of the fully expanded control form in admin area (Sidebar) //modified the width ref : #103336
                "id_base" => $idBase // ID of the widget container. This is used for multi-widgets . Id of each instance will be like {$id_base}-{$unique_number}
            );

            /* Create the widget. */
            $this->WP_Widget($idBase, $name, $widgetOptions, $controlOptions);
        }

        /**
         * Function to display the daily_quotes widget on the screen.
         *
         * @param   Array   $args   array of arguments
         * @param   Object  $instance   widget instance
         * @author  Test
         */
        function widget($args, $instance) {
            global $post;

            /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
            $title = apply_filters("widget_title", $instance["title"]);


            echo $args["before_widget"];
            Quotery_Quote::get_instance()->quote_html($instance);
            ?>
            <?php
            echo $args["after_widget"];
        }

        /**
         * function to update the widget settings in admin area.
         * @param   Object  $newInstance    New instance of the widget
         * @param   Object  $oldInstance    Old instance of the widget
         * @return  Object  updated instance of the widget
         * @author  Test
         */
        function update($newInstance, $oldInstance) {
            $instance = $oldInstance;

            /* Strip tags for title and name to remove HTML. */
            $instance["title"] = strip_tags($newInstance["title"]);

            $instance["author"] = strip_tags($newInstance["author"]);

            $instance['topics'] = Quotery_Quote::get_instance()->filter_in_array($new_instance['topics'], Quotery_Quote::get_instance()->get_topics_options());

            /* Strip tags for message and name to remove HTML. */
            $instance["topics"] = strip_tags($newInstance["topics"]);

            /* Strip tags for message and name to remove HTML. */
            $instance["border"] = strip_tags($newInstance["border"]);

        writeLog("Updated the daily quote with the new admin settings", basename(__LINE__), basename(__FILE__));

            return $instance;


        }

        /**
         * Displays the widget settings on the widget panel in admin area.
         * @param   Object  Widget instance
         * @author  Test
         */
        function form($instance) {

            $instance = wp_parse_args(
                    (array) $instance, Quotery_Quote::get_instance()->get_quote_default_settings()
            );

            /* Default widget settings. */
            $defaults = array("title" => "");
            $defaults = array("topics" => "");
            $defaults = array("border" => "");
            $defaults = array("author" => "");
            $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults);
            ?>

            <!-- Widget Title: Text Box -->
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("title"); ?>">
                    <?php _e("Title", "daily_quotes") . " : "; ?>
                </label>
                <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("title"); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name("title"); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance["title"]; ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('topics'); ?>"><?php _e('Topic:', $this->plugin_slug) ?></label>
                <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('topics'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('topics'); ?>">
                    <?php foreach (Quotery_Quote::get_instance()->get_topics_options() as $value => $name): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $value ?>"<?php echo $value == $instance['topics'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $name ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </p>

            <!-- Widget Title: Text Box -->
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("border"); ?>">
                    <?php _e("Border Color", "daily_quotes") . " : "; ?>
                </label>
                <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("border"); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name("border"); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance["border"]; ?>" />
            </p>

            <?php
        }

    }
    ?>




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iabkL.png
```

Comment: you should use `function __construct() {` instead `function Daily_Quotes()`

Answer (score 0):

> **Notice**:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Daily_Quotes is **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in **D:\xampp\htdocs\demowp\wp-includes\functions.php** on line **3891**

**Declaring a function then calling the parent constructor resolved this issue.**

```
class Daily_Quotes extends WP_Widget {
function __construct(){
   parent::__construct(...) // calls constructor from WP_Widget class
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Thanks, Can you please write down the section? Because I am confused about this. It will be very very helpful if you can help me.

Comment: I tried to write. but im getting error with code. `include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'class-quotery-quote.php' );` file not error

Comment: Can you please write the section where I need to add function __construct() this ?

Comment: can you please download the WordPress plugin from  https://wordpress.org/plugins/daily-quotes/

Comment: im getting this error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Quotery_Quote in D:\xampp\htdocs\demowp\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\class-quotery-quote.php on line 55`

Comment: Can you please download the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/daily-quotes/ and check? This is the plugin made

Comment: what you customize in that plugin?

Comment: Please check Appearance > widgets and please check whether you can see the sidebar widget section.

Comment: I am using Latest Wordpress version 4.7.2 . For me Sidebar section is not displaying.. My testers pointed out these things. please see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/iabkL.png

Comment: I setup the same in local machine. What about you?

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance. Actually our proxied are disabled. Thats the issue. Thankyou for your valuable time.

Comment: its ok. No problem

Comment: Can you please help me? I have another small doubt regarding admin areas settings email js validation.

Comment: yes. what is the issue?. can you post in Stackoverflow?

Comment: Sorry SO means?

Comment: I will paste the SO link here. OK?

Comment: Hello. I have reached question limit. So what should I do. Can you please do one thing? Can you please download the link https://wordpress.org/plugins/gift-certificate-creator/ . Please paste shortcode [gift_certificate_form] . Then add one form from the page(fron end). In admin area, please click on Settings > Then you will see a long button. I need to remove that button. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Hello Vel.. u checked?

Comment: Hello vel.. Have you checked??

Comment: I will check this today

Comment: It will be very helpful if you check now. I am sitting woth this for a long time.. Sorry..

Comment: I cannot see any button on admin panel

Comment: can you please check by clicking on gift-certificate button? there we can see the names and other details of particular user